# Why the program cannot find the system file specified and how to fix it?

Tags: java, file, file-io, network-programming, smtp

I wanted to test this program, but I don't get why it isn't working. It says it can't find file.txt, any reason why? I just wanted to have file.txt read the log protocol command messages from client and server, put them appended in a new file called "file.txt". It's saying it can't find the file specified. When I create the file manually in the same path, it works, but other than that, it won't. I want it to automatically create the new file and append the log messages, that's all.

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
 at SMTPDemo.main(SMTPDemo.java:28)
```

---

CODE:

```
/**
   Source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/SendingMailUsingSockets.htm
*/

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SMTPDemo 
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
   {
     String msgFile = "C:\\Users\\Jaime\\Desktop\\file.txt";
     String from = "java2s@java2s.com";
     String to = "yourEmail@yourServer.com";
     String mailHost = "localhost"; //changed from yourHost to localhost
     SMTP mail = new SMTP(mailHost);
     if(mail != null) 
     {
       if(mail.send(new FileReader(msgFile), from, to)) 
       {
         System.out.println("Mail sent.");
       } 
       else 
       {
         System.out.println("Connect to SMTP server failed!");
       }
     }
     System.out.println("Done.");
   }

   static class SMTP 
   {
     private final static int SMTP_PORT = 31000; //changed from 25 to 31000

     InetAddress mailHost;

     InetAddress localhost;

     BufferedReader in;

     PrintWriter out;

     public SMTP(String host) throws UnknownHostException 
     {
       mailHost = InetAddress.getByName(host);
       localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
       System.out.println("mailhost = " + mailHost);
       System.out.println("localhost= " + localhost);
       System.out.println("SMTP constructor done\n");
     }

     public boolean send(FileReader msgFileReader, String from, String to) throws IOException 
     {
       Socket smtpPipe;
       InputStream inn;
       OutputStream outt;
       BufferedReader msg;
       msg = new BufferedReader(msgFileReader);
       smtpPipe = new Socket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);
       if(smtpPipe == null) 
       {
         return false;
       }
       inn = smtpPipe.getInputStream();
       outt = smtpPipe.getOutputStream();
       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));
       out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outt), true);
       if(inn == null || outt == null) 
       {
         System.out.println("Failed to open streams to socket.");
         return false;
       }
       String initialID = in.readLine();
       System.out.println(initialID);
       System.out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
       out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
       String welcome = in.readLine();
       System.out.println(welcome);
       System.out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
       out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
       String senderOK = in.readLine();
       System.out.println(senderOK);
       System.out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
       out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
       String recipientOK = in.readLine();
       System.out.println(recipientOK);
       System.out.println("DATA");
       out.println("DATA");
       String line;
       while ((line = msg.readLine()) != null) 
       {
         out.println(line);
       }
       System.out.println(".");
       out.println(".");
       String acceptedOK = in.readLine();
       System.out.println(acceptedOK);
       System.out.println("QUIT");
       out.println("QUIT");
       return true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `String msgFile = "file.txt";`   Put the file in a reproducible path (such as a sub-directory of `user.home`).

Comment: I tried Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: `C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\file.txt`  Well?  Is the file actually *at that location* on the local file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `FileReader` with a file that does not exist will always throw a `FileNotFoundException`. The JVM typically only creates a file for you if you plan to write to it using a writer.

The above code does not make a whole lot of sense to me, but if you want it to run regardless of the file existing when you run this program for the first time, see [File.createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)

Comment: And as check you can put the following in your code

    `File f = new File(filePathString);`
    `if(f.exists()) { /* do something */ }`